# how to convert build.gradle.kts to old build.gradle

Tags: android, kotlin, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I want to convert this file in old build.gradle file, I am doing but there are alot of errors.
have searched too many google links but nothing happened.
I want to convert this file in old build.gradle file, I am doing but there are alot of errors.
have searched too many google links but nothing happened.

```
 import com.android.build.gradle.api.ApplicationVariant

    plugins {
        id("com.android.application")
        kotlin("android")
        kotlin("android.extensions")
    }

    android {
        compileSdkVersion(29)

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion(14)
        targetSdkVersion(29)
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "0.1.1"

        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {

            }
        }
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            setPath(File("${projectDir}/src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"))
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        getByName("main") {
            assets.srcDirs("src/main/assets", "build/ovpnassets")

        }
        getByName("debug") {
        }

        getByName("release") {
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        enable("BackButton", "EasterEgg")
        warning("ImpliedQuantity", "MissingQuantity")
        disable("MissingTranslation", "UnsafeNativeCodeLocation")
    }

    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            if (project.hasProperty("icsopenvpnDebugSign")) {
                logger.warn("property icsopenvpnDebugSign set, using debug signing for release")
                signingConfig = android.signingConfigs.getByName("debug")
            } else {
                signingConfig = signingConfigs.getByName("release")
            }
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions("implementation")

    productFlavors {
        create("ui") {
            setDimension("implementation")
            buildConfigField("boolean", "openvpn3", "true")
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            isEnable = true
            reset()
            include("x86", "x86_64", "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a")
            isUniversalApk = true
        }
    }
}

    var swigcmd = "swig"
    if (File("/usr/local/bin/swig").exists())
        swigcmd = "/usr/local/bin/swig"


    fun registerGenTask(variantName: String, variantDirName: String): File {
        val baseDir = File(buildDir, "generated/source/ovpn3swig/${variantDirName}")
        val genDir = File(baseDir, "net/openvpn/ovpn3")

    tasks.register<Exec>("generateOpenVPN3Swig${variantName}")
    {

        doFirst {
            mkdir(genDir)
        }
        commandLine(listOf(swigcmd, "-outdir", genDir, "-outcurrentdir", "-c++", "-java", "-package", "net.openvpn.ovpn3",
                "-Isrc/main/cpp/openvpn3/client", "-Isrc/main/cpp/openvpn3/",
                "-o", "${genDir}/ovpncli_wrap.cxx", "-oh", "${genDir}/ovpncli_wrap.h",
                "src/main/cpp/openvpn3/javacli/ovpncli.i"))
    }
    return baseDir
}

android.applicationVariants.all(object : Action<ApplicationVariant> {
    override fun execute(variant: ApplicationVariant) {
        val sourceDir = registerGenTask(variant.name, variant.baseName.replace("-", "/"))
        val task = tasks.named("generateOpenVPN3Swig${variant.name}").get()

        variant.registerJavaGeneratingTask(task, sourceDir)
    }
})


dependencies {
    val preferenceVersion = "1.1.0"
    implementation("androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0")
    implementation("androidx.core:core:1.1.0")
    dependencies.add("uiImplementation", "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.50")
    dependencies.add("uiImplementation", "androidx.core:core:$coreVersion")
    dependencies.add("uiImplementation", "androidx.core:core-ktx:$coreVersion")
    dependencies.add("uiImplementation", "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.1.0")
    dependencies.add("uiImplementation", "androidx.preference:preference:$preferenceVersion")
    dependencies.add("uiImplementation", "androidx.preference:preference-ktx:$preferenceVersion")
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.61")
}
```

Comment: What have you tried?  What errors do you get?  (And out of interest, why change back to groovy dsl?)

Comment: there are many errors during build project, I can't mention them, and I followed the documentations to replace the corresponding commands